# Scrapy unhandled error for unresolved URL's while respecting robots.txt

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, twisted

I am using **Scrapy==1.4.0** (Twisted==17.5.0) for crawling via script and not from console. I am using [errback=self.errback_httpbin](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing) for handling HTTPError, DNSLookupError and TCPTimedOut Error (I checked and all three exceptions are handled properly). This is working fine when I use **'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY' : False** (Not respecting robots.txt).
Now, when I start to respect robots.txt (**'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY' : True**). I get following error for URLs **which are not resolved** :

```
2017-07-24 15:59:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://example.com/robots.txt>: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: example.com.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1384, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 954, in startConnectionAttempts
    "no results for hostname lookup: {}".format(self._hostStr)
DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: example.com.
2017-07-24 15:59:30 [spidy_power] ERROR: <twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: example.com.>
2017-07-24 15:59:30 [spidy_power] ERROR: DNSLookupError on http://example.com
2017-07-24 15:59:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-07-24 15:59:30 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 2,
'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 2,
```

NOTE: I am not getting this error for URL's which have robots.txt but can be resolved. For those I am getting something like this (Which I guess is normal behavior):

```
2017-07-24 15:59:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET http://example.com>
2017-07-24 15:59:33 [spidy_power] ERROR: <twisted.python.failure.Failure scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest: >
```

Please suggest. Am I missing something? I want that this error can be handled and I can record the URL's which are forbidden to crawl due to robots.txt